# why if we assign a variable 0 it does not work properly in if else statement

Tags: c, if-statement, variable-assignment

**when i assign rat other than 0 its work properly if i assign rat=0 it's not working properly if rat is other than 0 my program work properly and give me proper prime number**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\nenter a number");
    int num,rat;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(int i=2;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            rat=0;
            break;
        }
        
    }
    if(rat==0)
    {
    printf("\nit is not a prime number");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nit is a prime number");
    }
  
}
```

Comment: You don't give `rat` an initial value, anywhere. Maybe it starts off as zero? Undefined behaviour.

Comment: `int num, rat = any-non-zero-value;`

Comment: why to initialize  as non zero

Comment: How would you know whether it is zero or non-zero if you don't reach the assignment `rat=0;`?

Comment: why does it works with every non zero value then

Comment: If you have to ask this, why did you put the line `rat=0;` in there? What ist the purpose of that line and how does it work?

Comment: Why initialize? What do you expect `int rat; if (rat == 0)` to do? Is the comparison true or false? It's neither; it's a bug!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `rat` is not initialized, so its value is undefined. You could initialize it to a non-zero value: this way the number is considered prime by default (since it falls under the `else` statement) and is marked as non-prime, if it's the case, after checking in the loop.